What's the physical meaning of Curl of Curl of a Vector Field?
The curl of curl of a vector field is, $$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) - \nabla^2 \mathbf{A}$$
Now, curl means how much a vector field rotates counterclockwise. Then, curl of curl should mean how much the curl rotate counterclockwise.
The Laplacian is divergence of the gradient of a scalar function. The Laplacian takes a scalar valued function and gives back a scalar valued function. While, $\nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})$ is a vector valued function (since it is gradient of divergence). How can we add these vector function and scalar function?
And how does $\nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})$ and $\nabla^2 \mathbf{A}$, i.e. gradient of divergence and divergence of gradient relate to curl?
And what does $\nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})$ and $\nabla^2 \mathbf{A}$ mean physically?

The Laplacian in your equation acts on a vector. For practical purposes in 3 dimensions this is to be interpreted as the usual Laplacian acting on each component of $\vec{A}$ individually. So it take a vector and returns a vector.

You are completely and unreservedly cool with this and this, right? These are basic geometrical operators based in fluid mechanics, in which students have little intuition, and mostly introduced in the electromagnetism of magnetic fields... Read on in your text.


curl means how much a vector field rotates counterclockwise. That is not so. Curl is a vector, it has direction of the surface area vector of an oriented area in which the circulation per unit area is the greatest, and magnitude is that circulation per unit area.


I know it's due to a misunderstanding of the vector Laplacian, but adding scalars and vectors is perfectly fine in geometric algebra.

As you note, the curl of the curl can be understood as a measure of the circulation of the circulation of a given vector field.
The curl operator is a measure of the "circulation" of a vector field, however, this is irrespective of the direction clockwise or counterclockwise.
The Laplacian is a differential operator that can be defined on both scalar valued as well as vector valued function, as it is in this case, thus both terms are vectors as is the curl of the curl. Thus, we might understand $\nabla^2\vec A$ as:
$$\nabla^2\vec A=\nabla^2A_x\mathbf{\hat i}+\nabla^2A_y\mathbf{\hat j}+\nabla^2A_z\mathbf{\hat k}.$$
How does $\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec A)$ and $\nabla^2\vec A$ relate to the curl? They have relationship to the curl because the following is provable using the basic rules of vector calculus:
$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec A)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec A)-\nabla^2\vec A.$$
There is really nothing deeper to know within the domain of the Heaviside formulation.

"The second term $\nabla^2\vec A$ is the Laplacian of the vector $\vec A$, which can be understood as a vector that serves as a measure of the average value of $\vec A$ at the point of evaluation." Can you elaborate on this? What is it averaged over if you just look at 1 point?

@Zaph It is averaged over a neighborhood of the point in question, i.e. it is a limiting process such that the radius of an open set about the point in question goes to zero.

@Zaph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Averages

Claiming that the Laplacian measures the mean value of a scalar/vector field averaged over a small region is misleading at the least I would rather call it wrong. You can add a constant to your field without changing the Laplacian at all, which changes the average. This is even supported by the formula Andrew linked, which does contain other terms then the Laplacian. In fact for the case $h = 0$ it does not contain the Laplacian at all.

From my understanding one might call it measuring the difference of the value of a function at a point from the value of a function averaged over a small region around the point. Or quoting the Wikipedia article linked by Andrew: “The Laplace operator itself has a physical interpretation for non-equilibrium diffusion as the extent to which a point represents a source or sink of chemical concentration.“

@Zaph Well, it is a matter of course that one will have to use gauge freedom to one's advantage as opposed to appealing to it to avoid saying anything, however, I do think what you have to say about the physical meaning of the Laplacian operator is more "physical" as opposed to mathematical. So, why don't you write a post?

@AlbertusMagnus I do not have enough intuitive understanding of the action of these double applied operators to provide the physical intuition that I understand OP is asking for. Failed too often myself when trying to envision Maxwell equations dynamical fields and potentials in my head. So I don’t really have much to say apart from throwing OPs own equation back at him. But you already did that. ._.
